# Absolutely-positioned elements with the same z-index: which element will be on top?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, z-index

Let's say you have several images in a `DIV` which are absolutely positioned such that they overlap but with *no z-index defined*:

**CSS**

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="...">
    <img src="...">
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

I've noticed that Safari and Chrome will display the *last* element on top. Is this standard behavior? In other words, is it *relatively* safe to assume that most browsers will display the last element on top?

Comment: by default the very last element renders on top, you need to use `z-index` property to change the element levels, btw learn css positioning

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Alien. I'm actually going to leverage this for a simple jQuery slideshow (so that I don't *have* to worry about z-index).

Comment: oh I got it, but than too learning something good wont harm ;) so do learn CSS positioning, it'll take your CSS knowledge to another level..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to assume. According to the **[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index)**:

> Each box belongs to one stacking context. Each positioned box in a
>   given stacking context has an integer stack level, which is its
>   position on the z-axis relative other stack levels within the same
>   stacking context. Boxes with greater stack levels are always formatted
>   in front of boxes with lower stack levels. Boxes may have negative
>   stack levels. **Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context
>   are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order**.

Comment: For the unsuspected reader, pay attention if the element stack order is affected by js.

Answer (score 4):

generally, the last activated will be on top.

```
div a is z-index 10, and appears first in the document

div b is z-index 10, and appears second in the document
```

when the document renders b will be above a, because a was written, then b written over top.

modifying a could bring it on top.

basically you should have a click handler on 'a' to raise it if you will ever need a to appear on top of b.

Comment: this is what I meant, but @kristopher, explain the `z-index` rather than just mentioning could bring it up ;)

Answer (score -1):

The last image in that same position read by the browser will be shown. Yes it's a safe bet that is the case in all browsers, because all files are read line by line.