# How tags with the same z-index work

Tags: html, css, z-index

Suppose that I added two tags with the same `z-index` attribute in its `style` (for example, 300).

I noticed that in Chrome the last element I've added will be on the top. Is it guaranteed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolutely-positioned elements with the same z-index: which element will be on top?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695313/absolutely-positioned-elements-with-the-same-z-index-which-element-will-be-on-t)

Comment: it "should" work that way in all browsers. if same z-index then latest is on top.

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed. Read about stacking order. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index